# What the function $f(n)=max{2^m|n} $ does?

Tags: functions

I got the following function $f(n)=max \{2^m|n\}$ when    $f:N \rightarrow N \cup 0$

I got those two examples $ f(3)=0$ and $f(6)=1$ maybe it have something to do with prime numbers?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean $f(n) = \max\{m\ |\ 2^m \text{ divides } n\}$.  This is the exponent of the largest power of two dividing $n$; equivalently, it is the number of copies of $2$ in the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: ... or the unique number $m$ such that $n$ can be written as $n=2^mu$ with $u$ odd.

Comment: Why is there Max for?